# Control macro usage formatting in Rustfmt

Tags: rust, rustfmt

I want to write a simple call to `assert!` like this

```rust
        assert!(idents.len() == 1, "Multi-part table references not supported");
```

But this keeps getting formatted to:

```rust
        assert!(
          idents.len() == 1,
          "Multi-part table references not supported"
        );
```

But I don't really like this particular formatting behavior; I'd like it to stay on one line. I tried setting the `fn_call_width` in my `rustfmt.toml` file to a higher number, but that didn't help. Note that my `max_width` is still the default value (`100`).

Does anybody know if there is a config I can set in the `rustfmt.toml` that can get me the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, I just realized that changing the width settings, like `fn_call_width` won't change anything if `use_small_heuristics` is set to `"Default"` (which it is by default). I have to either do `use_small_heuristics = "Off"`, or I have to increase my `max_width` (which `rustfmt` uses to compute settings like `fn_call_width` when `use_small_heuristics = "Default"`).